# Android Lollipop notifications

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-notifications

How to make something like this in Android using Lollipop notifications (pointed with red shapes):

[image: lollipop notification]

Here's how I implement a notification:

```
 NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
                    new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
            inboxStyle.addLine("jkl;adhjhasdkjhasdk");
            inboxStyle.addLine("jkl;adhjhasdkjhasdk");
            inboxStyle.addLine("jkl;adhjhasdkjhasdk");
            inboxStyle.addLine("jkl;adhjhasdkjhasdk");


            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_flight_takeoff_black_24dp)
                    .setContentTitle("Invitation")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                    .setDefaults(
                            Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                                    | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE
                                    | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS
                    )
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

[image: gmail like notification]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add actions to the Notification by setting **[Notification Actions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Action.html)**. 
It allows you to add the `PendingIntent` and the image icon to display along with it.

```
Notification.Action(int icon, CharSequence title, PendingIntent intent)
```

The icons can be set by using

```
.setLargeIcon(R.drawable.large_icon)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
```

Comment: ye, its works. What about the image icon with small rounded image at the bot left corner?

Comment: thanks. you helped me. One more question. what style should i use to make notification look like gmail notification

Comment: Which Gmail notification are you talking about? Can you share an image so that I know what exactly you are talking about?

Comment: I mean when you scroll the notification it's being expanded, and you can see the whole text, added image to the question

Comment: The style to use is InboxStyle. You can add lines using the addLine method. When you scroll down, it will show these lines. When the notification is collapsed, you can set the text using mBuilder.setContentText() and inboxStyle.setSummaryText(). Play around with these functions and you will get what you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your on custom Notification using RootViews (the way you want eg. large icon or small icon, textview position etc) . Just go through [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-custom-notification-tutorial/) tutorial.